# PHP multidimensional array search by key and return parents keys

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, key

I have array which looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    53 => array(
        'name' => 'category',
        'subcats' => array(
            42 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
            ),
            152 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
                'subcats' => array(
                    431 => array(
                        'name' => 'subsubcategory'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    94 => array(
        'name' => 'category'
    ),
    12 => array(
        'name' => 'category',
        'subcats' => array(
            67 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
            ),
            237 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
            ),
            109 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
            ),
            32 => array(
                'name' => 'subcategory',
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see keys are numbers, but those are IDs of categories which can be infinitely nested into each other. What I need is to search this array for specific ID and return array of it and its parents. We can safely assume that keys would not duplicate even in subcategories array - they are IDs from MySQL AI field;

So the expected result for searching key 431 would be:

```
array(53, 152, 431);
```

Any help would be appreciated, I just can't wrap my head around this ;)

Comment: What's wrong with recursive traversing? Did you try it?

Comment: @Rikesh yes it'a a duplicate, sorry for that. I've searched for answer, but this one just didn't come out as a result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works -

```
function find_id_list($array, $key){
    if(in_array($key,array_keys($array))){
        return Array($key);
    }
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(in_array("subcats",array_keys($v))){
            $result = find_id_list($v["subcats"], $key);
            if ($result !== null){
                array_unshift($result,$k);
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$val = find_id_list($array, 431);
var_dump($val);
/*  OUTPUT
    array
      0 => int 53
      1 => int 152
      2 => int 431
*/

$val = find_id_list($array, 109);
var_dump($val);
/*  OUTPUT
    array
      0 => int 12
      1 => int 109
*/

$val = find_id_list($array, 0);
var_dump($val);
/*  OUTPUT
    null
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to solve this issue.

```
function searchmulti($arr, $num)
{
    if (!isset($arr[$num])) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $subarr)
        {
            if (isset($subarr['subcats']))
            {
                $ret = searchmulti($subarr['subcats'], $num);
                if ($ret)
                {
                    $ret[] = $key;
                    return $ret;
                }
            }
        }
    } else return array($num);
    return null;
}

$solution = array_reverse(searchmulti($array,431));
```

Output

**$solution => array(53,152,431);**